# How to append a integer value to a textview name?

Tags: java, android

```
TextView text;
for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++) 
{
  text+j = new TextView(this);
 }
```

Expected Output:

```
text1 = new TextView(this);
text2 = new TextView(this);
text3 = new TextView(this);
```

But I get the error while runnig this code..

Comment: Sorry I think you're pretty much confused. This cannot be done. What do you want to do exactly? I think what you think as solution of your problem is wrong.

Comment: java101, chapter on variable names and accessing a variable.

Comment: Are you trying to do reference arithmetics in Java? Bad boy! ;)

Comment: Thnx all.. I understand that i cant name a variable dynamically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are better off uzing an array.

```
TextView[] tv = new Textview[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    tv[i] = new Textview(this);
```

The code you posted is trying to generate variabkles dynamically, which can not be done.

Answer (score 6):

This never works in Java . You cannot name a variable dynamically in Java . The name has be checked at the compile time itself. Hence expressions such as this `text+j` in the *L.H.S* will never work. You can use [arrays](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-arrays/).

You can define an array of `TextView` instead . Like :

```
final int SIZE = 3;
TextView[] textViews = new Text[SIZE];
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) 
{
   textViews[j] = new TextView(this);
}
```

Once all the elements in array `TextView[] textViews` are initialized , you can access individual elements using *index* , `textViews[0],textViews[1]....` . Remember arrays are indexed from `0` to `array.length-1`, in your case from `0` to `2`.

[image]

Comment: Thnx friend.. It worked

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append a integer value to a variable name in Java, like you are trying to do. What you want is an array of `TextView's`for your purpose. You can do it as following:

```
int textViewCount = 3;
TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];

for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) {
   textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
}
```

Hope this helps.